# Password Generator - Format combinations to a specific length

Tags: python

Trying to make a password generator based on a random combination of your personality traits and symbols+digits+alphabet. I think I understand where I want to go but I'm not sure how I make the format combinations to the length work. How do I go about achieving my desired output?

#Creating an object that holds all our alphabet, numbers and symbols.

```
import string                    
import random
all_1 = str(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation)
```

#Creating a list of numbers that can be used for our password length.

```
short_1 = [x for x in range(8, 10)] 
med = [x for x in range(15, 20)] 
long_1 = [x for x in range(23, 30)]
```

#Program Start

```
in0 = input("What are three things that come to your mind when you think about yourself? Please space out your answers! ")
personalitylist = in0.split() 
attribute = random.choice(personalitylist)
```

#Creating a list of formats for our passwords composed of the available combinations of attributes + all_1 variable.

```
combinationlist = [(attribute + all_1 + attribute), (all_1 + attribute + attribute), (all_1 + attribute + all_1)] 


in1 = int(input("Would you like a short, medium or long password length?"))
if in1.lower() =="short":
    passwordlength = random.choice(short_1)
    password = "".format(combinationlist)
```

My desired output is meant to look something like this:

```
user input = 'icy', 'mysterious', 'tall'
if short:
random length chosen = 10
random combination chosen = attribute + all_1 + attribute
output = icy902tall
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the trait length itself is too long for the random length chosen?

Comment: Good question. I might have to extend the length range for the chosen password lengths to counter that.